# Is it possible to loop all the elements of the list at once

Tags: python, python-3.x

Wanted to read folder contents and convert it as a dictionary.. My rudimentary approach below.

Code snippet:

```
import os

    b_path = "/home/work/assignments/chapters"
    output = {}
    
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(b_path):
        for name in subdirs:
            tmp = os.path.join(path, name)
            tmp_arr = [i for i in os.listdir(tmp)]
            for i, v in enemurate(tmp_arr):
                output[name] = [os.path.join(tmp, v)]
                output[name].append(os.path.join(tmp, <not sure how to achieve this> ))]
    print(output)
```

`subdirs` prints folder names -  `countries, social, algebra, functions` etc..

`subdir` (folder) contains 2 files under it, 1. yaml file, 2. zip or tar.gz file.

`tmp_arr's` output

```
['func.yaml', 'sensor.zip']
['packets.tar.gz', 'check.yaml']
['mt101.tar.gz', 'provider.yaml']
and so on.
```

I wanted my dictionary to look like:

```
{
    "countries": [
        "/home/work/assignments/chapters/countries/func.yaml",
        "/home/work/assignments/chapters/countries/sensor.zip"
    ],
    "social": [
        "/home/work/assignments/chapters/social/check.yaml",
        "/home/work/assignments/chapters/social/packets.tar.gz"
    ],
     and so on
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a folder structure like this :

```
Sample
│
└───folderA
│   │   A1.txt
│   │   A2.txt
│  
└───folderB
    │   B1.txt
    │   B2.txt
```

**Code**

```
import os

b_path = "Sample"
output = {}

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(b_path):
    for name in files:
        folder = os.path.basename(path)
        if output.get(folder) is None:
            output[folder] = [name]
        else:
            output[folder].append(name)

print(output)
```

**Output**

```
{'folderA': ['A1.txt', 'A2.txt'], 'folderB': ['B1.txt', 'B2.txt']}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it like this:-

```
import glob

D = {}
for _r in glob.glob('/home/work/assignments/chapters/*/*'):
    t = _r.split('/')
    if (d := t[-2]) in D:
        D[d].append(t[-1])
    else:
        D[d] = [t[-1]]
print(D)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
import os
def list_files(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        names=[]
        for name in files:
            print(name)
            r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
            names.append(os.path.join(root, name))
        output[root.split('/')[-1]]=names
    return output
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the alternate approach.

Answer (score 1):

How about an "one-liner" like this one?

```py
from os import sep
from glob import glob
from pprint import pprint

pprint({d.split(sep)[1] : [f for f in  glob(d +'/*.*')] for d in glob('/home/work/assignments/chapters/*/')})
```

`sep` for cross-platform support, `pprint` to "pretty-print", `d` for directory and `f` for file.